# How to perform an animation of a plane given by parametric equations

Tags: graphics3d, animation

How to perform an animation of a plane given by parametric equations:

```
{xo[t] + u1[t]*k + v1[t]*s, yo[t] + u2[t]*k + v2[t]*s, 
 zo[t] + u3[t]*k + v3[t]*s}
```

where `u = [u1[t], u2[t], u3[t]]` and `v  = [u1[t], u2[t], u3[t]]` are vectors on which is the plane spanned and vectors u and v are given by the parameter t. Also point `Xo = {xo[t], yo[t], zo[t]}` is given by the parameter `t`.

I do not want to use the InfinitePlane function.

Answer (score 2):

Is something like this what you have in mind?

```
u[t_] := {t, 1, 0};
v[t_] := {0, t, 1};
x[t_] := {5, 5, 5};

Animate[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  x[t] + s*u[t] + k*v[t],
  {s, -10, 10},
  {k, -10, 10},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]
  ],
 {t, 0, 5}
 ]
```

[image: Animated plane]

Comment: Dear Anne, this is exactly what I meant! Very warmly thank you! This is a great and elegant answer!

Comment: Wonderful, glad I could help!